# nslookup error : Non-authoritative answer name

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

i have DNS Server for local user. when PC user nslookup error name server like this

[error name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1FIi.png)

how to solved this error. my DNS running on Ubuntu 22.04

thanks

Comment: Do not post images or links to images when you can post the plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS server is not authoritative for testdomain.com (meaning it doesn't host the zone), and your client auto-padded suffix "co.id".

1. make sure testdomain.com is resolvable (by hosting that zone or forwarding it to other DNS servers that can resolve that domain)
2. To prevent auto-padding on one-off basis, try adding an ending dot in the name "nslookup xxx.testdomain.com."

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: then mark it as answer